# if $f(x)=x+x^3$ then what's $f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I was studying about functions that I faced with this
$$f:R→R$$ and $$f(x)=x+x^3$$ then

what's $f^{-1}(x)?$

I tried a lot but I could not solve it

Comment: Apparently this is what Wolfram Alpha thinks:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+function+of+x%5E3%2Bx. My only guess is this is found by solving $x=y^3+y$ for $y$ using standard formula

Comment: Perhaps (if this is homework) you were only asked to find $f^{-1}$ for some specific $x$, e.g. $f^{-1}(0)$, or $f^{-1}(2)$, or $f^{-1}(-2)$, or $f^{-1}(10)$, or $f^{-1}(30)$. Or you were only asked to prove that $f^{-1}(x)$ exists and is well-defined for all $x$, but were not asked to find it. You tried a lot ... what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $y=x^3+x$ where $y$ is an element belonging to the range $\mathbb{R}$.

So $$x^3+x-y=0$$

Now if you apply [Cardan's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method), you will get a value of $x$ in terms of $y$ and that will be your $f^{-1}x$.

Apparently you will get $$x^3=\frac{1}{2}\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+\frac{4}{27}}\right)$$

Hence you have $$f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+\frac{4}{27}}\right)}$$

**EDIT**: As mentioned by user236182, $f(x)=x^3+x$ is bijective, so $f^{−1}(y)$ has domain and range $\mathbb{R}$. The Cardano's method with $x^3+x−y=0$ gives the unique value of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in terms of $y$ for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$.